# C# ConcurrentDictionary used by 3 threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrentdictionary, blockingcollection

I have a class that uses a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

In this class, there are three functions that perform some operations on this `ConcurrentDictionnary`.

Each function is called by a different thread.

- First function operations : dictionnary.Where, dictionnary.TryRemove
- Second function operations : dictionnary.Where
- Third function operations : dictionnary.TryAdd

---

```
while (!dictionnaryKey.TryAdd(key, item))
{
  LogWriter.error_log("try add to dictionnary ...");
}
```

This last function blocks at different times. I have to add my element to the dictionary without blocking, but how can I do?

Comment: Why do you want to add an element without blocking? Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of a blocking collection, and on top of it you lose thread-safety. You might as well use a normal dictionary.

Comment: A normal dictionary with locks would be less performant than the concurrent dictionary. How do you measure the blocking?.. how many threads are you running concurrently?

Comment: A option of doing this is to have one additional thread who will take care of adding and removing and 2 stacks of dictionary one being the one for adding and the other for removing. If you want to add something in any thread you add it to the add stack (same with removing). In the extra thread you check in 1 sec intervals(or whatever) if there is something in either stack and then perform that operation accordignly, first add all from the add stack and then remove all from the remove stack

Comment: Enumerating a dictionary and writing to it at the same time might return mixed results that never existed at any point in time. I suspect that your whole concept is not as safe as you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I have to add my element to the dictionary without blocking, but how can I do?
```

That is not possible. The ConcurrentDictionary is optimized for multi-threading and low-contention, but that still doesn't mean there is no contention (blocking). All the write operations in a ConcurrentDictionary use a **fine-grained-locking** model, and multiple lock objects are used internally to sync the write operations to keep the data consistent and prevent multi-threading exceptions.

Your `TryAdd`method is evidently blocked because it is waiting for a lock (acquired by a different thread) to get released.

The reason why Concurrent dictionary enumerations (e.g. your `Where` operations) are not blocking is because they use a **lock-free** model.

Using a plain old dictionary instead of the ConcurrentDictionary would not yield any performance benefits, because you would have to handle the locking yourself using read-write locks.

As @Usr said in your comments, if your goal is to have non-blocking processing than your whole concept of using a single ConcurrentDictionary in your **multiple-writers** scenario might be wrong.